# What's the difference between the constructions "Не то что ... а ..." and "Не то чтобы ... но ..."?

Tags: грамматика

What's the difference between the constructions "Не то что ... а ..." and "Не то чтобы ... но ..."?

E.g. Is there any difference in meaning or style between the following two sentences:

Я не то что согласился с ним, а решил не продолжать спор.
Я не то чтобы согласился с ним, но решил не продолжать спор.

Comment: Please, add example sentences, without the context it's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: Не то что, а is a gradable comparative opposition, where two qualities or actions are compared emphasizing the more important one. Не то чтобы shows uncertainty.

Answer (score 4):

1.The thing or idea following the expression **не то что... (а)** can be compared to something '*stronger*':

> Он от этого **не то что** *расстроился* [это можно было предположить или это
>   само собой разумеется, но слишком мягко сказано], а (даже) *впал в
>   депрессию*.

A similar type of comparison can be found in this classical example (from Lermontov's poem):

> Да, были люди наше время - **не то что** нынешнее племя: богатыри - не вы!

2.The expression **не то чтобы... (а/но)** can be used in the *opposite* case - to *soften* the literal sense of the words said just after that expression:

> Он от этого не то чтобы впал в депрессию [это было бы слишком сильно
>   сказано], а/но был всерьёз расстроен.

The second of your 2 examples is correct—but it would sound more natural with **a** instead of **но**.

Answer (score 0):

A standard variation is `не то чтобы`. It sounds good.

Construction `не то что` is either very vernacular or does not exist (I haven't heard it before and to me it seems wrong).